# modify global variable when binding in tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, binding

I have the following code in tkinter

```
Row_n = 0
def new_line(event,Row_n):
    Row_n = Row_n + 1
    Choose = tk.Label(frame, text="Text", background = "white",font = ("Helvetica",13),fg = "blue")
    Choose.grid(row = Row_n, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
    print(Row_n)
    return Row_n

root.bind('<Shift-Return>',lambda event,Row_n = Row_n: new_line(event,Row_n))
```

This code generates a new row with the text "Text". The function new_line also returns the new value for the variable "Row_n" which should be the original Row_n + 1. The thing is that the value returned is always 1, because I can´t assign the value returned to the global variable Row_n. I need to find a way to assign the value returned to the variable Row_n so that the next time the function new_line is ran, the entry value for Row_n is 1 and the value returned is 2.

Thank you beforehand

Answer (score 1):

As you said you cannot update the `Row_n` from the return value of the event callback, so one of the way is declare `Row_n` as global inside the callback instead of passing it as an argument:

```py
Row_n = 0
def new_line(event):
    global Row_n  # declare Row_n as global variable
    Row_n = Row_n + 1
    Choose = tk.Label(frame, text="Text", background = "white",font = ("Helvetica",13),fg = "blue")
    Choose.grid(row = Row_n, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
    print(Row_n)

root.bind('<Shift-Return>', new_line)
```

However there is another way without using global variable by getting the rows used inside `frame` via `frame.grid_size()`:

```py
def new_line(event):
    # grid_size() returns (columns, rows)
    Row_n = frame.grid_size()[1]
    Choose = tk.Label(frame, text="Text", background="white", font=("Helvetica",13), fg="blue")
    Choose.grid(row=Row_n, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    print(Row_n)
```

I assume `frame` is used just for holding those labels.